# Adding symbols and patterns into Nested List in Python?

Tags: python-3.x

So I am trying to create a dungeon type game for my assignment. But I have no clue how to create a map like that with a nested list? Any help would be appreciated.

**Example of the map:**

```
+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
| T |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |
+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
|   |   |   | T |   |   |   |   |
+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
|   |   |   |   |   | T |   |   |
+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
|   | T |   |   |   |   |   |   |
+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
|   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |
+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
|   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |
+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
|   |   |   |   | T |   |   |   |
+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
|   |   |   |   |   |   |   | K |
+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
```

**The list:**

```
world_map = [['T', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' '],\
             [' ', ' ', ' ', 'T', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' '],\
             [' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', 'T', ' ', ' '],\
             [' ', 'T', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' '],\
             [' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' '],\
             [' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' '],\
             [' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', 'T', ' ', ' ', ' '],\
             [' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', 'K']]
```

**Here what I have:**

```
current_row = 0
current_column = 0

def View_Map():
    for i in world_map:
        world_map[current_row][current_column] = "H/T"
        print(i)
```

**The output I get:**

[image: Output]

Comment: You should read about the `str.join` method. Try to create one string from one sublist in `world_map` that looks like this: `"|   |   | T |   |   |   |   |   |"`. If you have figured out how to do this then maybe you will already know how to do the rest.

Comment: "The Dictionary:" – That's not a dictionary, that is a nested list. Do you actually want a dictionary?

Comment: Sorry, I'm not very good with Python. Yeah, the nested list was given as a template so would prefer it to be in a nested list form.

Comment: The posted code uses a loop to set the same field of your world_map over and over again to "H/T" and printing one line - setting the same field over and over is wasteful,you can do that outside the loop once and then print the map

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use string formatting to print this, you would need to print

- for each line in your data a header (`'+---+- etc -+---+'`))
- for each cell in your data a value *V* (`'+ V +'`)
- a end line after all of them  (`'+---+- etc -+---+'`))

Header and cells would need to adapt to the maximal widht of all cell contents to get an even looking map.

You can do it like this:

```
m = [['T', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' '], 
     [' ', ' ', ' ', 'T', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' '],
     [' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', 'T', ' ', ' '],
     [' ', 'T', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' '],
     [' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' '],
     [' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' '],
     [' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', 'T', ' ', ' ', ' '],
     [' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', 'K']]


def print_map(data):
    """Prints a list of lists, puts data centered
    into each boxand pads other boxes accordingly. """
    # max widht of all elelemts to be printed
    max_w = max(len(o) for l in data for o in l)
    # fitting header
    header = f"+-{'-' * max_w}-" * len(data[0]) + "+"
    for line in data:
        print(header)
        print("+", end="")
        for char in line:
            # center format each "box"
            print(f" {char:^{max_w}} +", end="")
        print()
    print(header)

print_map(m)
```

Output:

```
+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+ 
+ T +   +   +   +   +   +   +   +
+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
+   +   +   + T +   +   +   +   +
+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
+   +   +   +   +   + T +   +   +
+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
+   + T +   +   +   +   +   +   +
+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
+   +   +   +   +   +   +   +   +
+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
+   +   +   +   + T +   +   +   +
+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
+   +   +   +   +   +   +   + K +
+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
```

If you have a "non-1-character-content" the code will space out the other cells as needed:

```
+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+
+   T   +       +       +       +       +       +       +       +
+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+
+       +       +       + TTTTT +       +       +       +       +
+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+
+       +       +       +       +       +   T   +       +       +
+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+
+       +   T   +       +       +       +       +       +       +
+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+
+       +       +       +       +       +       +       +       +
+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+
+       +       +       +       +       +       +       +       +
+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+
+       +       +       +       +   T   +       +       +       +
+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+
+       +       +       +       +       +       +       +   K   +
+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+
```

[Lookup string format mini language for centering text](https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#formatspec)